# How to use facebook share plugin using bootstrap button?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use facebook share button to my wordpress theme. I have use this code for that

```
  <div class="fb-share-button btn btn-default" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  data-type="button_count"></div>
```

It is showing  the share button. You can check the result here http://www.racecarwow.com/crazy-crash-v2-0/ .  But my goal is , the share button will be look like the share button of this site http://blog.petflow.com/bravo-heroic-little-girl-saves-a-trapped-puppys-life/ .

I think, http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/ will be a good solution for me. But i could not understand how can i use `<div class="fb-share-button btn btn-default" data-href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  data-type="button_count"></div>` to that button. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ! i have got the solution by combining following the two site

http://ostr.io/code/html-social-like-share-buttons-no-javascript.html

http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/

Hope it will be helpful for other person.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears, that you have *a slight* mistake in your code, there is no function like `the_parmalink()` in Wordpress so far, but the correct one is `the_permalink()`.

This [function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink) retrieves the permanent link to the **post currently being processed** in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) (as you can guess from it's name).

This tag must be within `The Loop`, and is generally used to display the **permanent link** for each post, when the posts are being displayed. Since this template tag is limited to displaying the `permalink` for the post that is being processed, **you cannot use it to display** the `permalink` to an arbitrary post on your web site.

Refer to `get_permalink()` if you want to get the permanent link for a post, given its **unique post id**.

So fix your code and try again:

```
<div class="fb-share-button btn btn-default" data-href="<?php the_permalink();?>"  data-type="button_count"></div>
```